# Print the integers from 1 up to n (given number)

Tags: python, integer, int

so if the function is:

```
function(n)
```

what can i do to if i want.

```
function(5)
```

to return as

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I'm thinking towards creating an empty list, but i don't know what to append into the list to get the number `1 up to 'n'`

Comment: Are you familiar with `for` loops?

Comment: What answer do you want? `print` or `return a list`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
def function(n):
    for x in range(0, n):
        print x+1
```

if you want to print the values, or

```
def function(n):
    returnlist = []
    for x in range(0, n):
        returnlist.append(x+1)
    return returnlist
```

to return a list.

The `for x in range(0, n):` part of the code is called a for loop. It repeats itself n times, and x is incremented by one each time is repeats. You can then use x to accomplish different tasks within your code. In this case, we're simply taking its value plus one and printing it or appending it to a list. We have to add one to the value because x is zero based, although it doesn't have to be. We could just as easily have written `for x in range(1, n+1):` and not have had to add one to the x value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
def function(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print i
```